# Windows 10 file size does not update in the file explorer until the file is opened

Tags: file, logging, notepad++, refresh, tail

I am trying to monitor changes to the php error log.

Ideally I would like to monitor the changes using something like the `nix tail -f`.  I attempted this using **notepad++** as there is a silent monitor for changes within that editor but this did not work.

A deeper look showed that the file size displayed in file explorer did not change even after errors were generated and the <kbd>f5</kbd> refresh button was pressed.

After opening the log file, the errors were appended to the file as per usual.  Still no updates in the file explorer or notepad++.

Only a refresh performed after opening the file in a new instance of notepad updated the values for the size.  Still waiting for the update in notepad++.  Anybody else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

- Here is how to have Notepad++ update file automatically and display this line:

> `Preference -> Misc -> File-Status-Auto-Detection -> Scroll to the last line after update`

[image: Notepad++ MISC. options]

The thing is you have to toggle to another window, then back again for it to work.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work.  Only seemed to work for the first error generated when the WAMP was started.  After that, nothing.  I think there is an underlying problem in the WIN 10 environment.

Comment: Any alternatives?

Comment: @ReynaldoStBernard, if you use a share instead of a simple hard drive, it might be of help to check the sharing "advanced" options. But I'm not strong at Windows thing.

Comment: It is not a share, tried using a share too.  Same behavior.

Comment: @ReynaldoStBernard It's an issue with how often the "NTFS metadata" gets updated. Ref: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111226-00/?p=8813